# Adding an Image to the calendar View in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to add an image at the top of the default calendar view of the iPhone. If any body knows how to implement this please respond.I am using the Tapku library inorder to show the calendar. Kal library also can be used if this can implement there.

Below attached the calendar view and i need to put an image at the top of this calendar just below the title bar.The calendar need to see just below the image.

[image]

Comment: could you show your source code...?

Comment: hi @andikurnia please see this http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers

Comment: try to create UITableView that have 2 cells. first, for the image, and the second for the calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a subclass of TKCalendarMonthViewController and override loadView:

```
- (void)loadView {

    [super loadView];

    // Get the frame of the calendar view
    CGRect frame = self.monthView.frame;

    // Shift it down to make room for the image view
    frame.origin.y += 50; 

    // Add your image view, e.g. :  

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frame.size.width, 50.0)];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
```

If you're using TKCalendarMonthTableViewController, which include the table underneath the calendar view, then you'll need to resize the table too. See the loadView of the TKCalendarMonthTableViewController to see how it's set up.