# how to set images in the calender view iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im developing a calender based application and in that my client need to set a image on the particular date user selects.

For example if i select 1 and 20,an image is to be set on both the dates.

For now i can set the image only for one date i.e if i select 1 the image  is set on that date and when i select 20 the image set on 1 will disappear and image will set only for 20.

Can anyone please help me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/a/8399779/845115

Comment: What are you using to display the calendar, this most be something custom since the iOS SDK does not provide a component like this.

Comment: @MuditBajpai now i can set image for one date but need to set image for more than one date.Can you please help me.

Comment: I hope you will be having, one date reference as selectedDate,No you need two dates right?
If i am correct, use one more NSDate variable as selectedDate2, and check your conditions and add image as you are doing for first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a solution for this.I done in the method and you experts can suggest a better way for this.

```
- (void)selectButtonForDate:(NSDate *)aDate {



    if (selectedButton >= 0) {
        NSDate *todayDate = [CalendarLogic dateForToday];
        UIButton *button = [buttonsIndex objectAtIndex:selectedButton];

        CGRect selectedFrame = button.frame;
        if ([selectedDate compare:todayDate] != NSOrderedSame) {
            selectedFrame.origin.y = selectedFrame.origin.y + 1;
            selectedFrame.size.width = kCalendarDayWidth;
            selectedFrame.size.height = kCalendarDayHeight;
        }

        button.selected = NO;
        button.frame = selectedFrame;

        self.selectedButton = -1;
        self.selectedDate = nil;
    }

    if (aDate != nil) {
        // Save
        CGRect dayFrame;
        NSDate *dayDate;
        NSInteger numberOfWeeks = 5;
   //     NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
       // NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];   
   //     NSDate *todayDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

        for (NSInteger aWeek = 0; aWeek <= numberOfWeeks; aWeek ++) {
            CGFloat positionY = (aWeek * kCalendarDayHeight) + 60;

            for (NSInteger aWeekday = 1; aWeekday <= numberOfDaysInWeek; aWeekday ++) {
                CGFloat positionX = ((aWeekday - 1) * kCalendarDayWidth) - 1;
                dayFrame = CGRectMake(positionX, positionY, kCalendarDayWidth, kCalendarDayHeight);
                dayDate = [CalendarLogic dateForWeekday:aWeekday 
                                                 onWeek:aWeek 
                                          referenceDate:[name referenceDate]];
            //  NSLog(@" %@ todaydate [datesIndex objectAtIndex:[sender tag] %@",todayDate,[datesIndex objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]);
              //  NSDate *mmm = [datesIndex objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];
                if ([dayDate isEqualToDate:aDate]) {
                     NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

                    flag = 1;                 
                    [n addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:dayFrame]];



                    [currentDefaults setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:n] forKey:SaveMonth];
                    [currentDefaults synchronize];
            }



            }
        }
        if(flag == 1){

            flag = 0;
            for (int i=0;i<[n count];i++){


                UIImageView *im = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"call.png"]] ;
                CGRect myRect = [[n objectAtIndex:i] CGRectValue];
//                NSLog(@"n is %@",n  );
//                NSLog(@"frame 111111111111111  = %@\n", NSStringFromCGRect(myRect));

                im.frame = myRect;
                [self addSubview:im];


            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, I also try to do the same. Are you using the KAL library or something else?