# Load image in calendar in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, calendar

[image]
In my app, I want to implement the month wise calendar.

It should display the like as per following image.

**How can I implement the calendar like this?** *Is there any third party Library or any in-built classes for calendar?*

Thank you.

Comment: You can see <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060301/how-to-add-default-calendar-programatically-in-iphone-sdk/16061467#16061467"> my answer </a> that lists out all calendar controls available open source. Implementing month control is too easy use kal or tapku calendar in my answer others are also fine.

Comment: witch calender are you using in you Project..? check this may be its helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292889/how-to-set-images-in-the-calender-view-iphone

Comment: @NitinGohel, Thanks for your replay. the code which you suggested is uses the KAL Library or else?

Answer (score 0):

There is no library that will create this kind of calender view.I think you have to manage it by your code by creating a `custom view`.

Answer (score 0):

no any inbuilt class for this . you make a one image view in behind the calender and set your image customlly.